# Android call activity B's method from A's thread

Tags: android, multithreading, user-interface, android-activity

I have a main Activity A, in which I create a background thread to load data from db. After the loading is done, I want to update the list which might have been already shown in a child activity B (If user has navigated to B in the meanwhile). If user hasnt yet navigated to B, its not an issue.

But how to update B's list once thread in A has finished?

B is a child of A.

Thanks,

Comment: you will need to separate your data loading part from Activity to `IntentService` and register an `Broadcastreciver` to notify Activities when data loaded fully  from `Intentservice`

Comment: @EdwardSullen, not yet as could find anything yet.

Comment: @imran, I will try that, but no simpler solution for this?

Comment: @droidbee : i think Broadcast Receiver is only way to solve current issue. but you can also try using SheredPreferences or an extra Thread in Activity B

Comment: @imrankhan, I implemented ur soln of IntentService. My bg loading stuff requires querying db so I need a Context. If I make my IntentService as inner class, it does not ever get to run. If I make it a separate class, how to have Context there? getApplicationContext() does not work. Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Imran,

I handled it by creating an IntentService in a separate class (inner class was not working), and start it from A. After work is done I fire a BroadCast from the IntentService which B's broadcastreceiver is listening. It updates the list eventually.

Here is the code:

In class A, just start the IntentService in for ex OnCreate():

```
Intent contactIntent = new Intent(this, ContactLoaderService.class);
        startService(contactIntent);
```

Create IntentService like (in a separate class):

```
public class ContactLoaderService extends IntentService {
    public ContactLoaderService() {
        super("ContactLoaderService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent arg0)
    {
        populateContacts();

        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
        broadcastIntent.setAction(ContactsResponseReceiver.ACTION_RESP);
        broadcastIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
    }
}
```

In class B I create an inner class which just updates the list like:

```
public class ContactsResponseReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static final String ACTION_RESP = "com.a.b.c.ContactsLoaded";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        mCurrentAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

In B, dont forget to register the receiver. In B's onCreate() method:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ContactsResponseReceiver.ACTION_RESP);
filter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
receiver = new ContactsResponseReceiver();
registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

And the usual service tag in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<service android:name="com.a.b.c.ContactLoaderService"> </service>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the list as empty at first .You can take the user to activity B . Store the content of list dataand fill the list using a static list which is empty when the background thread is incomplete. Once loading from db is done called the notifydatasetchanged() method of the list's adapter .

An easy way to implement the background thread would be an asynchronous task . You can define different phases of the asynchronous tasks by overriding the corresponding methods.

Comment: The point is how to get reference of child activity in Thread which initiated in parent activity? Only then I can call notifydatasetchanged().

Comment: What i perceive is that initially you have some content with you that fills the list . Say you add it to the List . Keep a boolean flag for the buttonclick event that takes to child activity . If the flag is true , then call on notifydatasetchanged(delcare the adapter associated as static) if it's false then don't call . In either case you update the List to which you have added the initial content which again will have to be a static list.

Comment: And the check for the flag should be in the event that corresponds to the compltetion of the thread .